# regex \s and \S explanations

Tags: regex

Not part of any code but just trying to understand regex better

```
import re
test=re.findall('\s[0-9]+','hello 23and 4world ')
print test # works correctly 
[' 23', ' 4']
```

but

```
import re
test=re.findall('\S[0-9]+','hello 23and 4world ')
print test
```

I expected this output to be [] since '\S' matches any non whitespace character but the output is `['23']`. Any explanations will be helpful.

Comment: `2` is a digit but also a non white space character. `\S` matches `2` and `[0-9]+` matches `3`.

Comment: @HamZa Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`2` is a digit but also a non white space character. `\S` matches `2` and `[0-9]+` matches `3`:

```
hello 23and 4world 
      ^^-[0-9]+
      ^--\S
```

Which means `1234` would also get matched in `hello 1234and 4world`.

One way to "debug" this quickly is to use groups and [an online tester](https://regex101.com/r/gO5oS0/1): `(\S)([0-9]+)`.